# Conditional calculation in QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator, conditional

Is it possible in QGIS either directly or via plugins to do a raster calculation including an if statement?

e.g., if `raster1 > 0.3`, then `raster 1 * raster 2`, else `raster1 x raster3`... something like that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In QGIS Raster Calculator, the comparison return `0` (if `false`) or `1` (if `true`). So you can write a conditional using a sum of products.

```
((raster1@1 >0.3) * raster1@1 * raster2@1 ) + ((raster1@1 <=0.3) * raster1@1 * raster3@1 )
```