# Assign RasterB values to RasterA where B != no value in QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, raster-calculator, nodata

QGIS raster calculator is confusing me and I have no idea how to perform a very simple task.

I have 2 rasters, A and B:

Raster A has 9999 values on all pixels.
Raster B has different values including no data pixels.

I want Raster A pixel to = Raster B pixel where B != null

Which means Raster C(output) is 9999 **Except** where Raster B has values

Comment: What have you tried? See for example something like: [Conditional calculation - QGIS Raster Calculator or GRASS r.mapcalculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141305/conditional-calculation-qgis-raster-calculator-or-grass-r-mapcalculator)

Comment: I tried this, didn't work:

(("slope_clipped@1">0) * "9999@1" = "slope_clipped@1") + (("slope_clipped@1">0) * "9999@1" = 9999)

I.E.: 
if(rasterB_pixel >0){
  rasterA_pixel = rasterB_pixel
}
else{
rasterA_pixel = 9999 //do nothing
}

Answer (score 2):

The QGIS-documentation provides a very similar example-task: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html

According to the documentation, the following should work:

```
("slope_clipped@1" > 0) * "slope_clipped@1" + ("slope_clipped@1" = 0) * 9999
```

Naturally, if you didn't describe your data correctly to us, this wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without raster calculator, using [Fill NoData cells](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#fill-nodata-cells). Input is Raster B, `Fill value` is 9999.