# Redefine grid cell values of 0 to 365 in multiband raster

Tags: qgis, raster, r, multi-band

I have a multiband raster of the Arctic showing the day of the year on which snow melts. I have grid cell values that equal 0 but they should be 365 as the snow never melts. I have tried to use the `raster calculator` to set all the grid values that were 0 to 365:

`("arctic@1" = 0) * "arctic@1"`

, but this only gives me a true or false raster. I want it to be conditional, if `"arctic@1" = 0` then `365` else `"arctic@1"`.

I also visited [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141307/155292) advice, and it gave me values of 1.78e+308 and -1.78e+308 which is also wrong.

How can I perform a conditional statement in which I change the `0's` with `365's` for a multiband raster? I can do this in `Qgis` or `R`, but do not know how to perform it in the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For layer 2 of a layer called `zeroes`, this expression will replace zeroes with 365, and leave the rest unchanged:

```
 365*("zeroes@2" = 0) + "zeroes@2" * ("zeroes@2" != 0)
```

Comparisons with `=` return False if not equal, which is numerically interpreted as 0. The first part (before `+`) is then a raster of 365 where there is zero, and zero elsewhere, and the second part (after `+`) is a raster of the `zeroes@2` values unless its zero in which case its zero. Oh, that can be simplified (not tested):

```
 365*("zeroes@2" = 0) + "zeroes@2"
```

So that first part is 0 or 365 only, and then you add the layer back in again, and since 0+0 = 0 you end up with 365 where there was zero, and the original layer value elsewhere.

I can only see how to do this one layer at a time with the raster calculator though - maybe there's a way...

In R, starting with a stack `s`, you can replace values conditionally:

```
> z = s
> z[z==0]=365
```

and comparing `z` with what we started with you can see the zeroes are now 365s@

```
> table(z[])

  1   2   3   4 365 
  6  11   8   8   3 
> table(s[])

 0  1  2  3  4 
 3  6 11  8  8
```

Comment: Listen, you solved my week-old problem, I am eternally grateful!